Swiper starting at last index when slidesPerView is auto and centered slides is true
I am using Swiper with slidesPerView: 'auto', and it works perfectly, but it doesn't seem to work as expected when centeredSlides: true. I have created a  CodeSandbox to demonstrate the issue. It starts at the last index when centeredSlides is true.
I expect it to start based on the initial slide.
But it works perfectly fine when not using images, like here React Swiper Demos

I have found that even wrapping the img with a div with text works, but remove the text and it starts on the final slide again.
<div>               Text{index}               <img                 src={imageUrl}                 alt={Random ${index + 1}}                 style={{                   width: "100%",                   height: "300px",                   objectFit: "cover",                   borderRadius: "8px",                 }}               />             </div>
